# Do we need to run load_dotenv() in every module?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dotenv

I have a `.env` defined with the following content:

```
env=loc
```

I have three python module that make use of this variable.

```
├── __init__.py
├── cli.py
|── settings.py
├── commands
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── output.py
```

`settings.py:`

```
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()

if not os.getenv("env"):
    raise TypeError("'env' variable not found in .env file")
```

`output.py:`

```
import os

def output():
  return getenv("env")
```

`cli.py`:

```
import settings
from commands.output import output
import os

CURR_ENV = getenv("env") 
print(CURR_ENV)
print(output())
```

**Output:**

```
loc 
None
```

Why is the output from `output.py` not ***loc***? The environment variables were loaded when load_dotenv() was run for the first time.

Do I have to run load_dotenv() every time I need to access the environment variables?

Comment: `load_dotenv()` sets up environment variables. Environment variables are bound to a *process*; they don't care about modules/packages/files/etc. Once `load_dotenv()` has been called, environment variables will be visible in all of your modules (and in any child processes). If a variable isn't getting set, that suggests you have a code path in which `load_dotenv()` isn't being called. There's not enough of your code here to test that, however.

Comment: Hi @larsks Thanks for taking a look into it. I figured the issue out. In my actual code the import for `output.py` was before `settings.py` which is why it did not work as intended. The example in this question should work fine.

Comment: I have edited my question to reflect the same.